# QScrollArea widgets and layouts - PySide/PyQt

Tags: pyqt, pyside, qscrollarea

I've read endless examples on nullege, as well as previous questions on this topic on SO. I'm thoroughly confused with trying to set up a `QScrollArea` within my PySide UI project. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

A `QWidget` or `QFrame` which acts as a container on a page.
The `QWidget/QFrame` contains 8 Pixmapped labels.
Only 2 of the Pixmapped labels can 'fit' within the visible part of the screen at a time.
A `QScrollArea` is utilised such that the entire range of the `QWidget/QFrame` can be seen, using the horizontal scroll bars.

In theory this is really quite simple, but I just can't figure out how the `QScrollArea` links with the `QWidget/QFrame`, and whether I need a `QLayout` as well. At the moment, the horizontal scroll bars are present, but scrolling is unavailable. Here's what I have so far:

```
#Oscar Home Scroll Area - Scroll Area#
self.ScrollAreaOscarHome = QtGui.QScrollArea(self)
self.ScrollAreaOscarHome.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(12, 180, 1000, 570))
self.ScrollAreaOscarHome.setVisible(True)
self.ScrollAreaOscarHome.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)
self.ScrollAreaOscarHome.setObjectName("ScrollAreaOscarHome")
self.ScrollAreaOscarHome.setWidgetResizable(True)
self.ScrollAreaOscarHome.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
self.ScrollAreaOscarHome.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

#Oscar Home Container Widget - Widget#
self.WidgetOscarHomeContainer = QtGui.QWidget()
self.WidgetOscarHomeContainer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(12, 180, 2000, 570))
self.WidgetOscarHomeContainer.setObjectName("WidgetOscarHomeContainer")

self.ScrollAreaOscarHome.setWidget(self.WidgetOscarHomeContainer)

#Oscar Home Horizontal Layout - QHBoxLayout#
self.OscarHomeHorizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.WidgetOscarHomeContainer)
```

I've included the `QHBoxLayout` section above because previous examples I've read used the `Layout`, but I'm not sure how it fits in to the `Widget` and the `ScrollArea`.

Am I on the right track here? I'm not getting any errors, and the ScrollArea is displaying as I'd like, but the `ScrollArea` and Widget (which is much wider than the `ScrollArea`) don't seem to be linked at all.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried populating your container with the label contents? The scrollbar won't become active until the size of the contents exceeds the size of the viewport.

Comment: @SirHacksalot I think I have tried that, each of the labels has the QWidget as the parent. Is the QWidget the parent of the QScrollArea or is it the other way around? Due to this confusion I'm not actually sure what the 'viewport' is in this case.

Comment: The `QScrollArea` is the parent of the widget that you put the contents in (your WidgetOscarHomeContainer). You nearly have it in your code sample, just add widgets to the layout of your container widget.

Comment: @SirHacksalot Thanks for your help! So basically I make a QScrollArea to the dimensions that I want, which functions as the 'view port'. Then I add child Widgets to the QScrollArea, and if a Widget's dimensions cause it to fall outside the 'view port', the QScrollArea will automatically display scrollbars? That was my understanding from the beginning; getting the scrollbars to scroll has been the hard part!

Comment: @SirHacksalot Never mind mate, I've played around with it now and it seems to be working. I have the QScrollArea is the parent, a QWidget as the child (the QWidget's dimensions are larger than those of the QScrollArea), and the Pixmapped Labels as a child of the QWidget. Perfect! Thanks again :)